# Javascript wait for certain code to execute before calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript

I have below arrow function -

```
const handleSubmit=()=>{

const tObject={
  tId : store.Id,
  tAction:store.Action,
  tContent:store.content
}

let contentStatus=[];

if(storeContent!=null){
 contentStatus = storeContent.map((item:IContent)=>({contentId:item.contentId , content:item.content}));
}
submitRequest(tObject,contentStatus);
}
```

`submitRequest` is another arrow function which makes api call.
What is happening here is `submitRequest` sometimes gets called before `tObject` and `contentStatus` objects get assigned to their respective values. This makes api call to be called with empty values.

How can I make sure `submitRequest` is called after assignment of  `tObject` and `contentStatus` ?

**Edit1 :**

Can I assign object with await ?-

```
const tObject=await{
  tId : store.Id,
  tAction:store.Action,
  tContent:store.content
}
```

Note :- assume this with `handleSubmit` marked as `async`.

Comment: You can use `async` `await`.

Comment: @Ankit can you please check edit1 ? Can I make my object assignment await ?

Comment: It only makes sense to await async functions. Setting object properties is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize Async/Await keywords to ensure the code flow stops until *getObject()*

has returned its value successfully:

```
    const getObject = () => {
        return { tId : store.Id,tAction:store.Action, tContent:store.content }
    }   
 
    const handleSubmit= async ()=>{
        const tObject = await getObject()
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Edit: Note while using *await* you have to make the function *async* as done in above example.

Comment: Could you please check edit1 ? Is it possible to setobject like that using await ?